# "On" left join order

Tags: sql, outer-join

I've read through 20+ posts with a similar title, but failed to find an answer, so apologies in advance if one is available.

I have always believed that

```
select * FROM A LEFT JOIN B on ON A.ID = B.ID
```

was equivalent to

```
select * FROM A LEFT JOIN B on ON B.ID = A.ID
```

but was told today that "since you have a left join, you must have it as A = B, because flipped it will act as an inner join.

Any truth to this?

Comment: No  .. A.ID = B.ID or B.ID = A.ID are the same  ..  query change if you change the order of the table  ... FROM A LEFT JOIN B is not the same as  FROM B LEFT  JOIN A ..  because the set involved  c hange

Comment: The voting arrow mouseover texts address research. What is your agument for or against their claim or for or against their argument for their claim? (Why are you reading posts instead of authoritative reference definitions of left join & inner join?)

Comment: The "because" begs the question. They haven't given a reasoned argument--a chain of truths from an initial assumption via obvious basic valid logical rearrangements. What appeal do they make to definitions of left & inner join? (Even, what 1 illustrating execution have they run?) A definition of each join only involves evaluating an on condition en bloc for each row of the cross join of the tables & that is not affected by a flip. PS Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoever told you that does not understand how JOINs and join conditions work. He/She is completely wrong.

The order of the **tables** matters for a left join. `a left join b` is different than `b left join a`, but the order of the join *condition* is meaningless.

Comment: I felt like a complete idiot, I am glad this isn't true. Any chance this could be true for HQL?

Comment: @user8834780 That would be a new question :)

Comment: Re-wrote your example into HQL and still holds :)

Answer (score 3):

`A.ID = B.ID` is the condition on which the tables are joined and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. 
 
Since equality(`=`) is [**commutative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), the order of the operands does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely incorrect and it is trivial to prove.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @A(ID) SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @A(ID) SELECT 2

INSERT INTO @B(ID) SELECT 1

SELECT *
FROM @A a
LEFT JOIN @B b ON a.ID=b.ID

SELECT *
FROM @A a
LEFT JOIN @B b ON b.ID=a.ID
```

The order of the tables matter (A Left JOIN B versus B LEFT JOIN A), the order of the join condition group matter if an OR is used (A=B OR A IS NULL AND A IS NOT NULL - always use parentheses with OR), but within a condition group(a.ID=b.ID for example) it doesn't matter.